# Regex not extracting the second set of number

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file with entries like

```
ABC DEF GHI  1234<set 1 of numbers>          AT    <set 2 of numbers, can have decimal point>
```

I am using the following code to extract the 2 sets of number from each line.

```
if($_=~/ABC.*1234([0-9]+).*AT.*([0-9]+)/)
{
   print $_, "\n";
   print 1st number = ", $1 , "\t 2nd number = ", $2 , "\n";
}
```

While I am able to see correct value of 1st number, the second value shows up as 0 all the time.

Why I am not getting the second number?

Answer (score 3):

```
if(/ABC.*1234([0-9]+)\s*AT\s*([0-9.]+)/)
```

Comment: Much easier to see the requirments when there not swallowed by the markdown processor